# No download of PDF-files possible

Tags: php, pdf, download

I am trying to download PDF-Files onto the local computer.
Under Xampp with localhost the normal download-window appears. The download is not readable with Adobe.

The same is with an zip-download.

On my website this window does not appear, instead the pdf-file is shown in the browser-tab as gibberish.

So the pdf is definitely existing and somehow accessed and downloaded.

I can not find what is wrong with the code ...

Please help.

---

```
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST["hilfe_de"]))
       {
         $filepath = "dateien/";
         $file = "callershelp_help-de.pdf";
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
         header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
         header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filepath.$file));
         @readfile($filepath.$file);
       }
    ?>
    
    ... some html-stuff
    
    <form method="post">
      <table>
        <td>
          <tr>
            &nbsp;Callershelp_Hilfe_DE.pdf
          </tr>
        <tr>
          &nbsp;
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input type="submit" name="hilfe_de" value="Download">
        </tr>
      </td>
     </table
    </form>
```

Comment: Hello ManniS and welcome to stackoverflow! Please download the file and open it with a text editor (like Visual Studio Code, Notepad or Sublime Text). I believe there is an error message contained.

Comment: Put your PHP in a separate file with no whitespace before the opening `<?php` and no closing `?>`.

Comment: Please use comments and not answers for replying to the solution proposal or edit your post to add more information. `Answers` are intended for solution (proposals) :)

Comment: Which file should I open with notepad?

Comment: The one that is downloaded when you submit the form on your website. And you can add a `file_put_contents('debug.txt', $filepath.$file);` after `@readfile` to see how your path looks like on local and online environment.

Comment: The debug.txt (only available using Xampp) is only showing the complete and correct path to the pdf.

Comment: Live under: callershelp.de/downloads.php

Comment: It looks like you are serving the page and not the PDF. Move the `php` code to another file (say `download-submit.php`) and maintain it as `action` in the HTML form.

Comment: Done: <form action="new.php" method="post">

Comment: I have put the section with redfile into the new.php. 
An errormessege popped up:
  Bad Gateway
  The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.

Comment: `Bad Gateway

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.`
Is there any way to get more files/scripts of your project? I don't get why localhost and live should behave differently here.

Comment: No change. I give up for today 8-(

Comment: How can I send the files to you?

Comment: You can send a link e.g. to a github repository containing those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist solved:
PHP has sometimes problems with leading spaces.
I had indented the lines for better reading. Only after deleteing the leading spaces of the first 2 lines everything worked just fine. This took me a couple of days 8-(

```
    $filepath = '../path/';
    $file = 'file.pdf';
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
      header('Pragma: public');      
      header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filepath.$file));
      readfile($filepath.$file);
```

Unbelievable ...

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as accepted so that other users can easily find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are not supplying the full path and this is why `@readfile` can't read the PDF. You can use `dirname` for this:

```php
   
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/dateien/'; // equals the path of your script (__FILE__) plus the folder "dateien"
$file = "callershelp_help-de.pdf";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"'); // improvement, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#114450
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filepath . $file));

@readfile($filepath . $file);
```

Greetings from Germany,

Johannes